# Videogular is vg-controls are not working with vg-quality plugin

Tags: angularjs, videogular

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp',
    [
      "ngSanitize",
      "com.2fdevs.videogular",
      "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.controls",
    
      "th.co.softever.videogular.plugins.quality"
    ]
  )
  .controller('HomeCtrl',
    ["$sce", function ($sce) {
      this.config = {
        preload: "none",
        qualitySources: [
          {
            name: '720p',
            sources: [
              {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8274898/videogular/videogular720.mp4"), type: "video/mp4"}
            ],
            dashIndex: 3
          },
          {
            name: '480p',
            sources: [
              {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8274898/videogular/videogular480.mp4"), type: "video/mp4"}
            ],
            dashIndex: 2
          },
          {
            name: '360p',
            sources: [
              {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8274898/videogular/videogular360.mp4"), type: "video/mp4"}
            ],
            dashIndex: 1
          },
          {
            name: '240p',
            sources: [
              {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8274898/videogular/videogular240.mp4"), type: "video/mp4"}
            ],
            dashIndex: 0
          } /*,
          {
            name: 'Auto',
            sources: [
              {src: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8274898/videogular/dash/videogular.mpd"}
            ]
          } */
        ],
        theme: {
          url: "http://www.videogular.com/styles/themes/default/latest/videogular.css"
        },
        plugins: {
          controls: {
            autoHide: false,
            autoHideTime: 5000
          }
        }
      };
      this.currentQualitySource = this.config.qualitySources[this.config.qualitySources.length - 1];
    }]
  );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="sparta/dash.all.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.videogular.com/scripts/videogular/latest/videogular.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/vg-controls.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/vg-overlay-play.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/vg-poster.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/vg-buffering.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/vg-dash.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/mulit.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/vg-quality.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sparta/vg-quality.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="HomeCtrl as controller" class="videogular-container">
    <videogular vg-theme="controller.config.theme.url">
      <vg-media vg-src="controller.currentQualitySource.sources" vg-dash>
      </vg-media>

      <vg-controls vg-autohide="controller.config.plugins.controls.autoHide" vg-autohide-time="controller.config.plugins.controls.autoHideTime">
        <vg-play-pause-button></vg-play-pause-button>
        <vg-time-display>{{ currentTime | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
        <vg-scrub-bar>
            <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
        </vg-scrub-bar>
        <vg-time-display>{{ timeLeft | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
        <vg-time-display>{{ totalTime | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
        <vg-volume>
            <vg-mute-button></vg-mute-button>
            <vg-volume-bar></vg-volume-bar>
        </vg-volume>
        <vg-quality quality-sources="controller.config.qualitySources" default-quality="controller.currentQualitySource"></vg-quality>
        <vg-playback-button></vg-playback-button>
        <vg-fullscreen-button></vg-fullscreen-button>
      </vg-controls>
    </videogular>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to create  a simple video player and for that I have used the Videogular for it.  since my requirement included to  have a different resolutions video so I used the vg-quality plugin but with this plugin my other  controls are not coming and I m not been able to track the Issue

[image]

This is the only error coming and also the video is not playing nor any controls are coming in the chrome browser the mozilla is showing the video on the right mouse click with play button but still the actual controls are not coming

Comment: can you show the code you are using to declare this element?  This screen grab doesn't give any information necessary to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: I have edited the question with code as well @Claies

Answer (score 0):

Well Atlast I corrected the issue and the working example is here

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp',
  [
   "ngSanitize",
   "com.2fdevs.videogular",
   "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.controls",
    "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.dash",
   "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.overlayplay",
   "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.poster",
   "com.2fdevs.videogular.plugins.buffering",
   "th.co.softever.videogular.plugins.quality"
  ]
 )
 .controller('HomeCtrl',
  ["$sce", function ($sce) {
   var controller = this;
   controller.API = null;

   

  

   controller.config = {
    preload: "none",
    qualitySources: [
          {
            name: '720p',
            sources: [
              {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8274898/videogular/videogular720.mp4"), type: "video/mp4"}
            ],
            dashIndex: 3
          },
          {
            name: '480p',
            sources: [
              {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8274898/videogular/videogular480.mp4"), type: "video/mp4"}
            ],
            dashIndex: 2
          },
          {
            name: '360p',
            sources: [
              {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8274898/videogular/videogular360.mp4"), type: "video/mp4"}
            ],
            dashIndex: 1
          },
          {
            name: '240p',
            sources: [
              {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8274898/videogular/videogular240.mp4"), type: "video/mp4"}
            ],
            dashIndex: 0
          },
    {
            name: 'Auto',
            sources: [
              {src: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8274898/videogular/dash/videogular.mpd"}
            ]
          }
          
        ],
    autoHide: false,
    autoHideTime: 3000,
    autoPlay: false,
    
    theme: {
     url: "http://www.videogular.com/styles/themes/default/latest/videogular.css"
    },
    plugins: {
     poster: "http://www.videogular.com/assets/images/videogular.png"
    }
   };

   this.currentQualitySource = this.config.qualitySources[this.config.qualitySources.length - 1];
  }]
 );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.videogular.com/scripts/videogular/latest/videogular.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/vg-overlay-play.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/vg-poster.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/vg-buffering.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/dash.all.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/vg-dash.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/main.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/vg-quality.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.videogular.com/scripts/controls/latest/vg-controls.js"></script>
<script src="sparta/vg-quality.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sparta/vg-quality.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sparta/vg-quality.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sparta/videogular.css">
<style>
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.playlist ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

.playlist ul a {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #428bca;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.playlist ul a:visited {
 color: #428bca;
}

.playlist ul a:hover {
 color: #428bca;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.videogular-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 320px;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.videogular-container .skipButton {
 position: absolute;
 padding: 10px;
 top: 10px;
 right: 10px;
 z-index: 99999;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #666666;
 border: 2px #FFFFFF solid;
 display: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -ms-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
 .videogular-container {
  width: 1170px;
  height: 658.125px;
 }

 .videogular-container.audio {
  width: 1170px;
  height: 50px;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
 .videogular-container {
  width: 940px;
  height: 528.75px;
 }

 .videogular-container.audio {
  width: 940px;
  height: 50px;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
 .videogular-container {
  width: 728px;
  height: 409.5px;
 }

 .videogular-container.audio {
  width: 728px;
  height: 50px;
 }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl as controller">
 <div class="videogular-container">
  <videogular  vg-theme="controller.config.theme.url">
    <vg-media vg-src="controller.currentQualitySource.sources" >
   </vg-media>

   <vg-controls>
    <vg-play-pause-button></vg-play-pause-button>
    <vg-time-display>{{ currentTime | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
    <vg-scrub-bar>
     <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
    </vg-scrub-bar>
    <vg-time-display>{{ timeLeft | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
    <vg-volume>
     <vg-mute-button></vg-mute-button>
     <vg-volume-bar></vg-volume-bar>
    </vg-volume>
    <vg-quality quality-sources="controller.config.qualitySources" default-quality="controller.currentQualitySource"></vg-quality>
    <vg-fullscreen-button></vg-fullscreen-button>
   </vg-controls>
   
   <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
   <vg-buffering></vg-buffering>
   <vg-poster vg-url='controller.config.plugins.poster'></vg-poster>
  </videogular>
 </div>
 
</div>
</div>
<style>
videogular my-replay-plugin {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 50;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 pointer-events: none;
}
 
videogular my-replay-plugin div {
 background-color: #000000;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
 
videogular my-replay-plugin div span {
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-family: 'trebuchet ms', verdana, arial;
 font-size: 36px;
 display: table;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
</style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Probably you're using an old Videogular version that doesn't have support for playback button.

Comment: Well thanks @elecash It is now working but I still have one more problem since now I have to integrate the VG-quality source videogular to my json output file, can U guide me for this how to start the approach for connnecting the video player with the json file